# assign values from a dataframe to a new column in another datafraem base on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Dataframe that has date on it and I resample it monthly

```
**(T1)**
    date_gr         p
0  2017-03  24122.818182
1  2017-04  29696.000000
2  2017-05  37135.500000
3  2017-06  42871.555556
4  2017-07  46941.600000
5  2017-08  46963.750000
6  2017-09  40710.714286
7  2017-10  31212.200000
8  2017-11  28834.750000
9  2017-12  29319.666667
10 2018-01  28833.250000
11 2018-02  29657.800000
12 2018-03  28773.071429
13 2018-04  30049.142857
14 2018-05  34283.750000
15 2018-06  43694.222222
16 2018-07  51136.500000
17 2018-08  45297.250000
18 2018-09  39780.833333
19 2018-10  32073.600000
20 2018-11  28176.000000
21 2018-12  28315.250000
22 2019-01  28213.500000
23 2019-02  28886.500000
24 2019-03  26971.428571
25 2019-04  27644.875000
26 2019-05  38581.500000
27 2019-06  46501.857143
28 2019-07  50121.333333
29 2019-08  48226.250000
30 2019-09  42919.800000
31 2019-10  34589.571429
32 2019-11  29877.000000
33 2019-12  30223.000000
34 2020-01  30932.666667
35 2020-02  31630.800000
36 2020-03  27894.000000
37 2020-04  29523.000000
38 2020-05  40462.400000
39 2020-06  50798.428571
40 2020-07  51814.200000
41 2020-08  48111.714286
42 2020-09  46026.750000
43 2020-10  35544.000000
```

Now I need to create a new column and assign every monthly value you see above to it , base on month.I mean if value is for 2019-10 , The new column has 2019-10 value for all October days from 1 to 31.

for example we have :

```
   **(T2)**
        date_gr       p_ins
    0  2019-10-01  2122.818182
    1  2019-10-02  2696.000000
    2  2019-10-03  3135.500000
    3  2019-10-04  4871.555556
    4  2019-10-05  4941.600000
    5  2019-10-06  4963.750000
    6  2019-10-07  4710.714286
    7  2019-10-08  3212.200000
    8  2019-10-09  2834.750000
    9  2019-10-10  2319.666667
    10 2019-10-11  2833.250000
    11 2019-10-12  2657.800000
    12 2019-10-13  2773.071429
    13 2019-10-14  3049.142857
    14 2019-10-15  3283.750000
    15 2019-10-16  4694.222222
    16 2019-10-17  5136.500000
    17 2019-10-18  4297.250000
    18 2019-10-19  3780.833333
    19 2019-10-20  3073.600000
    20 2019-11-01  2176.000000
    21 2019-11-02  2315.250000
    22 2019-11-03  2213.500000
    23 2019-11-04  2886.500000
    24 2019-11-05  2971.428571
    25 2019-11-06  2644.875000
    26 2019-11-07  3581.500000
    27 2019-11-08  4501.857143
    28 2019-11-09  5121.333333
    29 2019-11-10  4226.250000
    30 2019-11-11  4919.800000
    31 2019-11-12  3589.571429
    32 2019-11-13  2877.000000
    33 2019-11-14  3223.000000
    34 2019-11-15  3932.666667
    35 2019-11-16  3630.800000
    36 2019-11-17  2894.000000
    37 2019-11-18  2523.000000
    38 2019-11-19  4462.400000
    39 2019-11-20  5798.428571
```

We need to find the month value in (T2) that its month matche (T1)'s month and assign its value to every day of that month.We must do this for every month and day.

```
output:

            date_gr       p_ins          p
        0  2019-10-01  2122.818182  34589.571429
        1  2019-10-02  2696.000000  34589.571429
        2  2019-10-03  3135.500000  34589.571429
        3  2019-10-04  4871.555556  34589.571429
        4  2019-10-05  4941.600000  34589.571429
        5  2019-10-06  4963.750000  34589.571429
        6  2019-10-07  4710.714286  34589.571429
        7  2019-10-08  3212.200000  34589.571429
        8  2019-10-09  2834.750000  34589.571429
        9  2019-10-10  2319.666667  34589.571429
        10 2019-10-11  2833.250000  34589.571429
        11 2019-10-12  2657.800000  34589.571429
        12 2019-10-13  2773.071429  34589.571429
        13 2019-10-14  3049.142857  34589.571429
        14 2019-10-15  3283.750000  34589.571429
        15 2019-10-16  4694.222222  34589.571429
        16 2019-10-17  5136.500000  34589.571429
        17 2019-10-18  4297.250000  34589.571429
        18 2019-10-19  3780.833333  34589.571429
        19 2019-10-20  3073.600000  34589.571429
        20 2019-11-01  2176.000000  29877.000000
        21 2019-11-02  2315.250000  29877.000000
        22 2019-11-03  2213.500000  29877.000000
        23 2019-11-04  2886.500000  29877.000000
        24 2019-11-05  2971.428571  29877.000000
        25 2019-11-06  2644.875000  29877.000000
        26 2019-11-07  3581.500000  29877.000000
        27 2019-11-08  4501.857143  29877.000000
        28 2019-11-09  5121.333333  29877.000000
        29 2019-11-10  4226.250000  29877.000000
        30 2019-11-11  4919.800000  29877.000000
        31 2019-11-12  3589.571429  29877.000000
        32 2019-11-13  2877.000000  29877.000000
        33 2019-11-14  3223.000000  29877.000000
        34 2019-11-15  3932.666667  29877.000000
        35 2019-11-16  3630.800000  29877.000000
        36 2019-11-17  2894.000000  29877.000000
        37 2019-11-18  2523.000000  29877.000000
        38 2019-11-19  4462.400000  29877.000000
        39 2019-11-20  5798.428571  29877.000000
```

How can I do that in pandas? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches.  One thing you could do is take your monthly data and convert each date to the start of the month.  Then you can use `merge_asof` to join the two data frames.

```
# Add day one to each monthly value
t1.date_gr = t1.date_gr + '-01'

# Convert to datetime objects
t1.date_gr = pd.to_datetime(t1.date_gr)
t2.date_gr = pd.to_datetime(t2.date_gr)

# merge t2 to closest previous date in t1
pd.merge_asof(t2, t1, on='date_gr', direction='backward')
```

Output

```
      date_gr        p_ins             p
0  2019-10-01  2122.818182  34589.571429
1  2019-10-02  2696.000000  34589.571429
2  2019-10-03  3135.500000  34589.571429
3  2019-10-04  4871.555556  34589.571429
4  2019-10-05  4941.600000  34589.571429
5  2019-10-06  4963.750000  34589.571429
6  2019-10-07  4710.714286  34589.571429
7  2019-10-08  3212.200000  34589.571429
8  2019-10-09  2834.750000  34589.571429
9  2019-10-10  2319.666667  34589.571429
10 2019-10-11  2833.250000  34589.571429
11 2019-10-12  2657.800000  34589.571429
12 2019-10-13  2773.071429  34589.571429
13 2019-10-14  3049.142857  34589.571429
14 2019-10-15  3283.750000  34589.571429
15 2019-10-16  4694.222222  34589.571429
16 2019-10-17  5136.500000  34589.571429
17 2019-10-18  4297.250000  34589.571429
18 2019-10-19  3780.833333  34589.571429
19 2019-10-20  3073.600000  34589.571429
20 2019-11-01  2176.000000  29877.000000
21 2019-11-02  2315.250000  29877.000000
22 2019-11-03  2213.500000  29877.000000
23 2019-11-04  2886.500000  29877.000000
24 2019-11-05  2971.428571  29877.000000
25 2019-11-06  2644.875000  29877.000000
26 2019-11-07  3581.500000  29877.000000
27 2019-11-08  4501.857143  29877.000000
28 2019-11-09  5121.333333  29877.000000
29 2019-11-10  4226.250000  29877.000000
30 2019-11-11  4919.800000  29877.000000
31 2019-11-12  3589.571429  29877.000000
32 2019-11-13  2877.000000  29877.000000
33 2019-11-14  3223.000000  29877.000000
34 2019-11-15  3932.666667  29877.000000
35 2019-11-16  3630.800000  29877.000000
36 2019-11-17  2894.000000  29877.000000
37 2019-11-18  2523.000000  29877.000000
38 2019-11-19  4462.400000  29877.000000
39 2019-11-20  5798.428571  29877.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,Is there any way to use a condition at the same time as when I merge it? (A condition base on other columns data)

Comment: I'm sure there would be, perhaps ask another question specific to that.

Comment: It's important to notice that it work with "forward" keyword on the way I need